# ssrs using two lookup with replace

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two datasets and I want to look for a value in each dataset with Lookup. For example if we have dataset1:

```
SELECT Persons.clname, Persons.Sex, Persons.clcode, Persons.Memid
```

And dataset2:

```
SELECT Persons.clname, Persons.Sex, Persons.clcode
```

How can we mix two lookups in a single expression:

```
Lookup(Fields!memid.Value, Fields!memid.Value, Fields!sex.Value, "dataset1") 

Lookup(Fields!clcode.Value, Fields!clcode.Value, Fields!sex.Value, "dataset2")
```

And finally, if we have "M" replace it with "Male" and, if we have "F" replace it with "Female"?

Comment: why not build everything in one stored procedure and just display the result in RDL?

Comment: Thanks, it worked with stored procedure!